# An anime film set in post-apocalyptic world where it looked like machines were killing humans

Tags: a-wind-named-amnesia

In the early 2000, I rented an anime film from the library. The film was set in a post-apocalyptic world where it looked like machines were killing humans. I remember that the main character was talking about when he had amnesia and he looked in a mirror and punched it. There was blood from his hand and he commented about it. Also he helped a couple five birth in this post apocalyptic world in the middle of the film. I think near the end there was a woman who was dressed in a clear dress and they were basically having sex at the end of the movie. I cannot remember the title for the life of me and I was hoping someone knows what I am talking about.

Answer (score 4):

The first result in a Google search for "anime post apocalyptic kill human amnesia" is:

### [A Wind Named Amnesia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Wind_Named_Amnesia) (1990)

[image: Theatrical pamphlet for the film "A Wind Named Amnesia"]

> The Apocalypse didn't come with a bang, but with a whimper. Silently, the amnesia wind swept away all of mankind's knowledge. Thousands of years of human civilization vanished overnight as people forgot how to use the tools of modern civilization: who they were, how to speak—everything. Technology decayed as mankind was reduced to the level of cavemen.
>
> Two years later, a young man—miraculously re-educated after the cataclysm—explores this barbaric world while pursued by a relentless killing machine. He is accompanied by a young mysterious woman who is somehow spared the devastating effects of the amnesia wind.

- Post-apocalyptic world where it looked like machines were killing humans — Check.
- Main character had amnesia — Check.
- Main character looked in a mirror and punched it and bled — [Check](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QZArbMgc72M&t=9m50s).
- Near the end there was a woman and they were basically having sex — [Check](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QZArbMgc72M&t=74m12s).